# Import contacts and friends from social networks and email providers in an asp .net website

Tags: asp.net, api, social-networking

I want to include in my asp .net website ( c# ) a function to import contacts and friends from my social networks and email providers. I would prefer if I don't have to choose the option of redirecting to each social network. I would rather have an API which can provide me the functionality of giving the credentials and return my contacts from each social network. DO you have something to propose to me?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a way to do OAuth requests without actually going through OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the OpenContacts.Net controls

OpenContacts.NET is open-source library for importing contacts from popular web-mail services. Now supports: GMail, Yahoo! Mail, Live (Hotmail).

Here is the url to the project: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencontactsnet/